# html con modal bootstrap estilo confirm

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Intenté con lo poco que se de javascript y hasta con jquery pero estoy trabado hace dias. El codigo que copio abajo al clickear en el icono lapiz de bootstrap me ejecuta un confirm, si le doy "no" cancela, con "si" sigue la ejecución. Necesito lo mismo pero que muestre el formulario modal de bootstrap que necesito configurar. Al final del codigo comente lo que consegui sobre bootstrap. Podrían ayudarme como implementarlo ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Prueba</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="p-5">
                    <table class="table align-middle overflow-auto table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Código</th>
                                <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
                                <th scope="col">Editar</th>
                                <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php 
                                $centros = array(
                                '1' => array(
                                    'id' => 1,
                                    'CODIGO' => 1000,
                                    'DESCRIPCION' => 'CENTRO 01',
                                ),
                                '2' => array(
                                    'id' => 2,
                                    'CODIGO' => 1005,
                                    'DESCRIPCION' => 'CENTRO 02',
                                ),
                                '3' => array(
                                    'id' => 3,
                                    'CODIGO' => 1008,
                                    'DESCRIPCION' => 'CENTRO 03',
                                ),
                                '4' => array(
                                    'id' => 4,
                                    'CODIGO' => 1010,
                                    'DESCRIPCION' => 'CENTRO 04',
                                ), 
                                '5' => array(
                                    'id' => 5,
                                    'CODIGO' => 1012,
                                    'DESCRIPCION' => 'CENTRO 05',
                                ),                                                                      
                                );

                                $estado=100;
                                foreach($centros as $datos): 

                            ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td><?= $datos['CODIGO']?></td>
                                <td><?= $datos['DESCRIPCION']?></td>
                                <td><a onclick="return confirm('Está seguro/a de eliminar?');" class="text-successs" href="eliminar.php?codigo=<?php echo $datos['id']; ?>"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a></td>
                                <td><a class="text-successs" href="#"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up-circle"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php endforeach ;?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>


<!-- ------------------------------ -->
<!--    CODIGO MODAL DE BOOTSTRAP   -->
<!-- ------------------------------ -->
<!--     <div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>Seguro de editar ?</p>' +
                </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" id="boton1" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                  <button type="button" id="boton2" class="btn btn-secondary">Ok !</button>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> -->
```

Comment: Tus etiquetas dicen bootstrap-4 y bootstrap-5, pero en tu código usas bootstrap-3. Puedes (o deberías) usar únicamente una versión

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te recomiendo [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download)

agregas esto
`<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>`

y en el js esta la alerta

```js
function confirma_eliminacion(id){
  Swal.fire({
    title: '¿Esta seguro de eliminar el item?',
    text: "¡No podrás revertir esto!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Si, Eliminar!'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      document.location="eliminar.php?codigo="+id;
      
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Prueba</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="p-5">
                    <table class="table align-middle overflow-auto table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Código</th>
                                <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
                                <th scope="col">Editar</th>
                                <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= $datos['CODIGO']?></td>
                                <td><?= $datos['DESCRIPCION']?></td>
                                <td><a onClick="confirma_eliminacion(3);" class="text-successs"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a></td>
                                <td><a class="text-successs" href="#"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up-circle"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php endforeach ;?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

para que funcione deje ei id fijo, eso lo debes de cambiar